# Gray scale image color

Tags: image

In color image every pixel has three colors Red, Green and Blue (**RGB**). When I convert a color image into gray image as far I know there will be only two color Black and White.

My question is how I will get the integer value of Black and White component after conversion.
I have found a conversion code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/grayscale_conversion.htm). In this code every time they replace each color component with sum of three colors.

But I want to know which part is Black and which part is white.

```
Color c = new Color(colorImage.getRGB(i, j));
int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.299);
int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.587);
int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.114);
int sum = (red + green + blue);
grayImage.setRGB(i, j, new Color(sum, sum, sum).getRGB());
```

Comment: Grey is just the color you get when you have equal amounts of all 3 colors.

Comment: In color Image if I change Red value and compare the real image and changed image the changed appear more than changed in blue component. Did this property is same in gray image.

Comment: A gray image have the three components with the same value (`sum` in your case). Depending on the value of `sum` you will have different shades of grey. If you look for True Black or True White check for a value of 0 or 255. But you can always put thresholds to set dark zones to Black and bright zones to White.